# Как получить username из id, telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

Как получить username из id, telebot?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

не уверен что нам понадобится id вообще

```
message.from_user.username
```

Comment: Так этой мой юзернейм, а мне нужен юзернейм другого юзера, ид которого я имею, но я уже понял как это сделать, не знаю на сколько это правильно, но работает ->
bot.get_chat_member(user_id, user_id).user.username

Answer (score 0):

Так этой мой юзернейм, а мне нужен юзернейм другого юзера, ид которого я имею, но я уже понял как это сделать, не знаю на сколько это правильно но работает ->

```
bot.get_chat_member(user_id, user_id).user.username
```